# Servicenow Service Portal, creating a Save button for the form widget in a custom widget

Tags: widget, servicenow, portal

I currently have a custom portal with a custom version of the form widget that doesn't have any UI Actions (OOTB inclusive).

We also have a custom widget (let's call it "actions widget") where we control all the actions we need to take in the record.

Currently I need to create a "Save" button inside the actions widget where the user, after filling the form, can click on the save button to update the record.

I am unable to find any way to make this button work. The keyboard shortcut "CTRL + S" works perfectly but I have no idea what type of functions and/or methods this shortcut calls.

If this is too complicated or not possible I can also fetch the fields one by one (there is not a lot of them) and update the record with that information.

Can you guys assist me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the hope that answering this will be helpful to others, I'll sketch out how you would need to approach this.  The broad outline is that your "form" widget needs to accept a message by having a block like:

```
$rootScope.$on('messageName', function(evt, parms) {
  // do some handling
  });
```

If you want to have several buttons in your control widget, you can have multiple handlers like that, with different message names, or one handler with different parameters.

Then, in your control widget, you will need to have each button send a message through a command (again, in the client script) like:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('button.pressed', 'save');
```

There are other ways to handle it (embedding both widgets in a third widget, and using the $scope of that widget instead of $rootScope, for instance), but this is the simplest.